# Can't remove stuck rear dirt bike axle

Tags: motorcycle, wheels, axle

I'm trying to remove the rear wheel on my 2007 Suzuki RMZ450. I've removed the axle bolt and tried banging the axle with a rubber mallet for about two weeks now. IT WON'T BUDGE. Not even a little bit. It seems to be completely seized up. What can I do to loosen it up and eventually remove, hopefully saving the wheel bearings at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I have to compliment your stamina. I doubt I'd be able to keep swinging a mallet for two whole weeks.

Soak the area in a good penetrating oil. I like Wurth's Rost Off, but there are many choices. Hit it with penetrating oil once or twice a day for a while. Give it a few whacks with a mallet, if it doesn't loosen up, hit it with more penetrating oil, and come back tomorrow. Repeat until it's off.

Otherwise, I think you might have to resort to using a torch to heat the bearings or the axle.  After the torch treatment, I'd replace the wheel bearings.

Comment: Ha! Yes I'm a modern day John Henry. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try them out. And when you said "Wurth's Rost Off", did you mean "Wurth's Rust Off"?

Comment: Nope, they spell it "Rost." German company.

Comment: Ended up having to set a block of wood up against the axle and bang away with a real hammer. Also used a good bit of penetrating oil. Thanks for the help!